# rails fullCalendar, How can I show end time of a event but omit the title of the event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have checked a lot of related questions, but no one actually solve my problem.

I am now writing a rails app and use fullCalendar.

I am able to show events on my calendar, but with start time and the title of the event.

Actually these is end time for the even under the month view, and events longer than 30 mins under the week and day view. But no end time for the events of duration less than 30 minutes under view of week and day.

Besides, I hope not to show the title of the event. I find other answers says it will need to change the source file of fullcanlendar, I am wondering if there is any way to do it without changing the souce code of full calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the eventRender callback:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

With this, you can alter the event's html element however you need to.